# Connect Mysql to Excel without ODBC

Tags: excel, odbc

I want to connect mysql to excel to analyze data from my database, but my provider does not allow use ODBC,
How you could make that connection?
Is there any other equally powerful tool that you can use Excel via web?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're using Excel online (Office 365) or using Excel on-premises?

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question now, but this is now possible. Modern Excel files are now simply zipped XML files. You can even change the file extension to .zip and open or extract them with your favorite unzip utility.

That being said, the "new" way to interact with Excel files is with the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-sheets). Details of how the files are structured are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-spreadsheetml-document).

A NuGet package is freely available from Microsoft for both "classic" .NET 4.8.x and for newer versions like .NET 7. (I've personally successfully used it in both) - ODBC is not required.